# Integração Jenkins com plugin GIT local

Tags: git

Boa tarde;

Eu estou precisando fazer a integração do servidor GIT com o jenkins para que os deploys sejam feitos automaticamente, porem as configurações que encontro são com referencia com o GIThub ou GITlab eu preciso fazer a integração do meu servidor local do GIT com meu jenkins local.

os procedimentos que estou usando são:

1 Gerenciar Jenkins > Configurar o sistema > Git plugin.
a- Global Config user.name Value = git
b- Global Config user.email Value = user@dominus.com

1 criei um projeto Freestyle no jenlins
3 no Gerenciador de código fonte selecionei GIT.
4 em Repository URL: ssh://git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos
5 Credencials "a chave SSH"
6 Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') esta "/master

Em seguida ja aparece esta mensagem:
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/ HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout
stderr: Permission denied, please try again
Received disconnect from server1.dominus.com port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Authentication failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

"A BIULD: retorna o seguinte"

Building on master in workspace /root/.jenkins/workspace/teste git

> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git config remote.origin.url git@ # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   using GIT_SSH to set credentials deploy
>   git fetch --tags --progress git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@10.160.0.119:/home/httpd/html/
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1155)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1798)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
>   Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
>   Permission denied, please try again.
>   Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2016)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1735)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:420)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:886)
>       ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'.

Porem o servidor jenkins eu consigo conectar via linha de comando ao servidor repositorio.

" git ls-remote -h git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/ "
Password:
25395b853cba048ea91ec4c1        refs/heads/master"

Alguém teria uma sugestão para ajudar!

Comment: O seu Jenkins está hospedado na mesma rede do server1.dominus.com? A máquina do Jenkins tem acesso ao git de server1.dominus.com? Tenta logar na máquina Jenkins e fazer um ping para server1.dominus.com.

Comment: Sim os servidores estaio na mesma rede, e consigo acesso do servidor jenkins para o servidor1.dominus.com por senha e através de chave  RSA
o comando git clone it@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/ via terminal funciona sem erros o comando it ls-remote -h git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/ HEAD também funciona sem retorno de erros

 ~$ git ls-remote -h git@server1.dominus.com:/projetos/
25395b853cba048ea91ec       refs/heads/master

Comment: Me parece problema de permissão da chave usada  no git clone: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). Tenta mudar: chmod 700 .ssh &&  chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: Boa realmente eram as configurações de permissão agora esta conectando sem problemas através de chave RSA;
fiz estes passos:
 chmod g-w /home/your_user
 chmod 700 /home/your_user/.ssh
 chmod 600 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Resolvido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa realmente eram as configurações de permissão agora esta conectando sem problemas através de chave RSA;

fiz estes passos:

chmod g-w /home/your_user

chmod 700 /home/your_user/.ssh

chmod 600 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Resolvido